# Div positioning (overlays when not wanted)

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a **header** div, inside it there are also divs **header-left-box** and **header-right-box** that float left and are placed side-by-side horizontally.

After those I want to place a div **receiver** that would take the space that is free below.

The problem is the **receiver** div is not displayed below the other, it is on top of others, 'overlaying'. What can I do about it? I want **receiver** to be below the other divs.

Here is the code:

```
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-left-box {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#header-right-box {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#header-right-box-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#header-left-box p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;  
}

#receiver {
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    border: solid 1px green;
}

</style>

<title></title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-left-box">
        <p>Left header box</p>
    </div>
    <div id="header-right-box">
        <div id="header-right-box-content">
            <p>Right header box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="receiver">Receiver</div>    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you applied clear:both to the header? To force the other div below it?

Comment: Do you mean adding clear: both; into style of #header? I have tried that, didn't work...

Comment: Could it be the position attribute causing the issue? As the receiver is relative

Answer (score 2):

Make the receiver as absolute position with top just a little more than 30%. it will work as you need.

```
#receiver {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
    top: 35%;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8wRte/1/

Comment: Yes you need to set the value for top more than 30% as your upper section is of height 30%.

Answer (score 0):

Receiver is overlaying because your `#header-left-box` and `#header-right-box` are `position:absolute` and the receiver is `position:relative`. Your solutions would be to either position your header left and right boxes to `relative` OR position your receiver to `absolute` and add a `top:(place height of header left and right boxes here)`.

here's a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/hRcYF/) where everything is `positioned:relative`. The receiver needs to be `float:left (or right)` and the `#header-right-box` needs to be floated right for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this much easier, why not making `#header-left-box{float:left}` and `#header-right-box{float:right}`
The #receiver div is placed above because of the using of absolute position. It's not a good practice to use position like this, so try to remove position from all your css elements that you don't need.
Look at this example:http://jsfiddle.net/E7T9F/ .
Don't forget that you can position you element without using css::position by different techniques like padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute positioning is not needed everywhere. Withdraw them and make sure you are not floating the `#header-right-box` to the left. Also make sure you are clearing the `#receiver`. Like so-

```
<style type="text/css">
#header {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header-left-box {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#header-right-box {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#header-right-box-content {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#header-left-box p {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.9em;  
}

#receiver {
    position: relative;
    clear: both; /*Cleared previously floated elements*/
    width: 98%;
    border: solid 1px green;
}
</style>
```